# Flutter elements's of the Grid View not rendering cornerRadius

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

this is my issue:

I have a GridView.count with a List.generate as children. Basically I have a grid of maps made with google_maps_flutter and I want to give each of them a corner radius but it applies only to the last element of my list , I've tried putting corner radius everywhere:

inside a box decoration wrapping my elements inside a container, various tries never worked.
wrapping in a clipRRect, still applies only for the last element.
giving to my custom widget Map a corner radius, still applies only for the last element.
I think it is a render problem, when I run my app on a physical device and not the simulator, it works well for every cell in android, but in iOS there is still the problem. please help.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAwtF.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FPAO.png)

I want all the cells to have a border radius